# How to convert jsp code to html using sightly in AEM 6.1?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, aem, sightly

I want modify jsp code to html using sightly in AEM .Here jsp scriptlet and **pageContext.setAttribute("coltype", xssAPI.filterHTML(properties.get("coltype","")));** --> this piece of code is getting the value from dialog and storing into jsp. likewise how to do in html using sightly concept.

```
<jsp:directive.include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"/>
<cq:includeClientLib categories="bootstrap" />
<jsp:directive.page session="false" />

<!-- <%=properties.get("coltype","")%> -->

<jsp:scriptlet>
    pageContext.setAttribute("coltype", xssAPI.filterHTML(properties.get("coltype","")));
</jsp:scriptlet>

<c:if test="${empty coltype}">
     Responsive Grid and Column Control Component
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty coltype}">

<c:set var = "column" value = "${properties.coltype}" />
<c:set var = "color" value = "${properties.color}" />
<div class="row">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '8-4-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-8 ${color}" ><cq:include path="col-8-4-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-8-4-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '4-8-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-4-8-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-4-8-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '4-4-4-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-4-4-4-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-4-4-4-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-4-4-4-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '6-6-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-6 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-6-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-6-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '3-3-3-3-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-3-3-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-3-3-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-3-3-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-3-3-4" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '2-2-2-2-2-2-col'}">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-2-2-2-2-2-2-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-2-2-2-2-2-2-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-2-2-2-2-2-2-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-2-2-2-2-2-2-4" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-2-2-2-2-2-2-5" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-2-2-2-2-2-2-6" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '3-9-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-9-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-9-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '9-3-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-9  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-9-3-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-9-3-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '3-3-6-col'}">
            <div class=" col-sm-3 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-6-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class=" col-sm-3 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-6-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-3-6-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '6-3-3-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-6  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-3-3-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-3-3-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-3-3-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '6-2-2-2-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-6  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-2-2-2-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-2-2-2-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-2-2-2-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2  ${color}"><cq:include path="col-6-2-2-2-4" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${coltype eq '3-6-3-col'}">
            <div class="col-sm-3 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-6-3-1" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-6-3-2" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 ${color}"><cq:include path="col-3-6-3-3" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys" /></div>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sightly provides a [display context](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/expression-language.html#Display%20Context) to prevent XSS security issues by default. Mostly, it detects the context automatically, however you can explicitly specify the context too.

The JSP code would translate to something like this in Sightly.

```
${properties.coltype @ context='html'}
```

Comment: Dialog values were able to display .. My question is how to pass variable to sighlty. How jsp scriptlet passing variable "coltype" to jstl tag by setting variable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JavaScript Use API:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html#Passing%20Parameters%20to%20a%20Template

There is a small example on how to access data and pass it to the sightly html code using the server side JS Use API (there is also a Java Use API available, or as an alternative, Sling Models, but those might be a little bit overweight for your purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Hi following is the sample code for passing variable using sighlty :

```
<sly data-sly-test.colomType="${properties.coltype}" />
<sly data-sly-test.color="${properties.color}" />
```

above "**columType**" and "**color**"is like a variable, you can use these variable like below:

```
    <sly data-sly-test="${columType== '8-4-col'}">
        <div class="col-sm-8 ${color}"><sly data-sly-resource="${'col-8-4-1' @ resourceType='/libs/foundation/components/parsys'}" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><sly data-sly-resource="${'col-8-4-2' @ resourceType='/libs/foundation/components/parsys'}" /></div>
    </sly>
    <sly data-sly-test="${columType== '4-8-col'}">
        <div class="col-sm-4 ${color}"><sly data-sly-resource="${'col-4-8-1' @ resourceType='/libs/foundation/components/parsys'}" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 ${color}"><sly data-sly-resource="${'col-4-8-2' @ resourceType='/libs/foundation/components/parsys'}" /></div>
    </sly>
```